# Why Trident/8.0? A newer version for IE11?

Tags: web-services, logging, user-agent

Going through logs and came across:

```
Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/8.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729)
```

I know `Trident` displays the actual browser when in compatibility mode and it goes up to `Trident/7.0` for IE11. But I cannot find information about `Trident/8.0`. What browser(version) does `Trident/8.0` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some research and it seems to be an an IE11 on a Widows 10 with compatibility view settings. That could change the user agent string to something like the one you posting. You could find more of such [“Trident/8.0” agents here](http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=%22Trident%2F8.0%22&include=yes&class=all&do=desc). But I am not 100% sure because I have no Windows installation to experiment with. May be someone could verify it.